# For any two almost complex structures on infinite-dimensional space: Do they give isomorphic vector spaces? Are they similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here are some:

**Assumptions**: Let $W = (W,\text{Add}_W: W^2 \to W,s_W: \mathbb R \times W \to W)$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space, which may be infinite-dimensional. Suppose $W$ has an almost complex structure $H \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(W)$. $H$ uniquely corresponds to the $\mathbb C$-vector space $(W,H)$, where scalar multiplication is given by the complex structure $s_W^{H}: \mathbb C \times W \to W$, $s_W^{H}(a+ib,v) := s_W(a,v) + s_W(b,H(v))$. Note that $s_W^{H}$ agrees with the original real scalar multiplication $s_W$.

**What I know**:

- A1. For $W$ finite-dimensional and for any other almost complex structure $J \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(W)$, we have that $(W,H)$ and $(W,J)$ are $\mathbb C$-isomorphic but not necessarily by the identity map $id_W$ on $W$.
- A2. For $W$ finite-dimensional and for any other almost complex structure $J \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(W)$, we have that $H$ and $J$ are similar, i.e. $H \circ S = S \circ J$, for some $S \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(W)$
- A3. (A2) may be proven using (A1). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688617/how-many-complex-structures-are-on-mathbbr2n) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546426/action-of-gl2n-r-on-set-of-linear-complex-structures). (I'm not sure if [Moore (Section 9.1)](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf) uses (A1)).

**Questions**:

1. Is (A1) true if $W$ were instead infinite-dimensional? (You may use axiom of choice.)
2. Is (A2) true if $W$ were instead infinite-dimensional? (You may use axiom of choice.)

**What I've tried**:

- If yes to Question 1, then I think yes to Question 2 because I think we can still make the same argument as in the answers in the links in (A3). If no to Question 1, I think we don't necessarily have no to Question 2.

**Related question**: [Different almost complex structures: $\mathbb C$-isomorphism for $(W,K)$ and $(W,H)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518395/different-almost-complex-structures-mathbb-c-isomorphism-for-w-k-and-w)

Comment: I am puzzled how you can have a proof for this in the finite-dimensional case that does not trivially generalize to the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks Eric Wofsey! As I edited post to include allowing axiom of choice, I forgot about [simply considering bases](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3532758)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and I don't know of any proof in the finite-dimensional case that does not also work in the infinite-dimensional case with trivial modifications.  Given an almost complex structure $J$ on $W$, you can think of $W$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space via $J$.  Pick a basis $B$ for this $\mathbb{C}$-vector space.  Then $B\cup J(B)$ is a basis for $W$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.  So, $\dim_\mathbb{R} W=2\cdot \dim_\mathbb{C} W$.  In particular, this means that $\dim_\mathbb{C} W$ is uniquely determined by $\dim_\mathbb{R} W$ (it is half the dimension when it is finite, or the same dimension when it is infinite).  So any other almost complex structure $H$ makes $W$ a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of the same dimension as $J$ does, so they are isomorphic.

Note that question 2 is equivalent to question 1.  Indeed, $S:W\to W$ witnesses that $J$ and $H$ are similar iff $S$ is an isomorphism $(W,J)\to (W,H)$ of complex vector spaces (this is trivial from the definitions).

Comment: Thanks Eric Wofsey! As I edited post to include allowing axiom of choice, I forgot about [simply considering bases](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3532758)